# A process inside "System" causes periodic slowdown

Tags: windows-10, performance, nvidia-graphics-card, cpu-usage

I've read some other pages but most of them describe the process taking massive amounts of CPU **constantly**.

I've encountered this on pretty much every computer that has been with me for a long time, so clearly I've been doing something wrong for years now. Approx. every 9 seconds, the computer freezes for about 2 seconds, no matter whether it's overloaded with programs or completely free.

[Screenshot of CPU performance from Task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIgKQ.png)

[Screenshot of a 1min analysis from Windows Performance Analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP1Uw.png)

This process is related to NVidia as far as I can tell. Other people that have encountered similar problems don't seem to have found a universal solution for all machines.

System is Win10 - it is up do date.
Graphic Drivers - just updated as well.
Machine is relatively new - 3 months old.

Answer (score 0):

Nvlddmkm.sys relates to your NVIDIA video card.

You could try using DDU ([Display Driver Uninstaller](https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html)) to completely remove the driver and then reinstall directly through NVIDIA's website instead of GeForce Experience.